# Probability of dying after 10 days is 50% -- interpretation.

Tags: probability

I'm solving a problem where I'm told the probability of dying after 10 days is 50% (the person is guaranteed to live in the first 10 days), and the probability of living forever is therefore 50% (this problem assumes you have a chance of being immortal).

If you let $D_i$ indicate you dying on the i-th day, then $D_i$ is mutually exclusive with $D_j$ for $i \neq j$ since you can't die twice. So this means $P(\bigcup_{i=10}^{\infty} D_{i}) = 0.5$.

What I am confused about is does the statement imply that $P(D_i) = P(D_j) \ \ \ \forall i,j \in \{1, \ldots, \infty\}$? i.e., the marginal probability of dying on each day is the same.

Or does the marginal probability of dying on each day increase as we live longer? The conditional probability of dying on the i-th day, conditioned on not dying on all the previous days, goes up as $i$ increases, I believe.

Comment: Since $D_1, D_2, ...$ are mutually exclusive and the probability of dying after 10 days is 0.5, you have by the 3rd axiom of probability: $$0.5=P[\cup_{i=11}^{\infty}D_i] = \sum_{i=11}^{\infty} P[D_i]$$  Questions for you: (1) Can you give **one** example of $P[D_i]$ values for $i \in \{11, 12, ...\}$ that satisfy this? (2) Can you show it is **impossible** to have $P[D_i]$ the same for all $i\geq 11$? (3) Can you show it is **impossible** to have $P[D_{i+1}]\geq P[D_i]$ for all $i \geq 11$?

Comment: @Michael Hmm, so it seems my first interpretation isn't correct based on your questions, but I still don't understand why it isn't correct. Is this because the possible values for $i$ is unbounded?

Comment: Perhaps you can give answers to the questions in my first comment.  For example the first question is asking you to come up with nonnegative numbers that sum to $0.5$. This is very easy to do and I think doing so will give you a significant amount of intuition.

Comment: @Michael I did think about that question, but I feel like it depends on why the probability of dying on each day isn't equal. If it was equal then the answer is 1 divided by the number of days, which is technically infinity. So I suppose this doesn't make sense why the probability would be equal on each day, because if it were the case, you'd have that the probability is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$. Is this the right idea? If so, I will try to answer your questions.

Comment: I don't know what $n$ means. There is no reason the probabilities should be equal (that would be jumping to conclusions) but if you want to answer question 2 first then you can assume there is some value $p$ such that $$P[D_i]=p \quad \forall i \in \{11, 12, 13, ...\}$$ and then reach a contradiction. For question 1, the sample space is $$S = \{\mbox{live forever} \} \cup D_1 \cup D_2 \cup D_3 \cup ...$$ so you just give an example  where you assign probabilities to these elementary events. And you are already told $P[D_i]=0$ for $i \in \{1, ..., 10\}$ and $P[\{\mbox{live forever}\}]=0.5$.